# White Space Above Logo And Menu Bars on Mobile (WordPress)

Tags: css

I am building a WordPress website and there is a HUGE white space above the menu bar and logo on Mobile and tablet. Any idea what HTML/CSS code can be used to correct this and bring the menu bars and logo back up towards the blue?

[image]

Comment: Please include your code via a [mcve]; we can't debug screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the guilty mmenu-link. Its style is causing troubles.

```
<a href="#mobile-menu" class="mmenu-link" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">
    <i class="fa fa-navicon"></i></a>
```

Here is the css that I accessed **since none was provided**: [the-core-style.css](https://haloglobalgov.com/wp-content/uploads/the-core-style.css)
You can add css to override the following, or you can edit the same:

```
 .fw-logo-retina.header-5 .fw-header:not(.fw-header-sticky-new-logo)
 .mmenu-link {
          margin-top: 308.25px;
         }
```

You can view what my browser showed here: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXB87.png)